# Is it bad to use UIKit with React.js?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, getuikit

I am asking this because both React and UIKit manipluate the dom.

Is it a bad idea to use them together ?

Comment: Probably.  There's pretty much always a way to get React to do any sort of DOM manipulation if your components are structured properly.  This question will probably get closed as "too broad" unless maybe you add an example of how you're using UIKim to manipulate the DOM and we can show you how to do it with just React.

Comment: From the docs: https://getuikit.com/docs/javascript#uikit-and-reactive-javascript-frameworks